# what's the exact differences between jsch ChannelExec and ChannelShell?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Can someone tell me the differences between`ChannelExec` & `ChannelShell`?

Comment: Just to make sure about the first sentence: did you know of the [manual in the wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Manual), and my [Javadoc](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/)? The examples are not really clear about this, if you didn't read the RFC's.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The shell and exec channels](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Shell,_Exec_or_Subsystem_Channel) are quite similar - both execute commands with the remote shell (at least, conceptually - the server might be configured to treat them differently, of course). RFC 4254 groups them in the [section "Interactive Sessions"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4254#section-6), and they both (as well as subsystem, see below) use the channel type "session" in the SSH protocol.

There is one important difference:

- For [`ChannelShell`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelShell.html), the input stream provides both the commands and input to these commands. This is like **using an interactive shell** on your local computer. (And it is normally used just for that: interactive use.)
- For [`ChannelExec`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html), the commands are given with setCommand() before `connect()`, and the input stream will be forwarded to these commands as input. (Most often, you will have only one command, but you can provide multiple ones using the normal shell separators `&`, `&&`, `|`, `||`, `;`, newline, and compound commands.) This is like **executing a shell script** on your local computer. (Of course, if one of the commands itself is an interactive shell, this will behave like a `ChannelShell`.)
- There is a third similar one, [`ChannelSubsystem`](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSubsystem.html), which executes a subsystem of the ssh server - here the server's configuration decides what to do, not the remote user's shell. (The most often used subsystem is `sftp`, but for this JSch provides a specialized channel, which understands the protocol.)

Note that what I call "input stream" here is the stream of data in the channel from the local to the remote host – that can be actually be done by passing a Java InputStream to the `setInputStream` method, or by getting a Java OutputStream from the `getOutputStream` method and writing to it.

Comment: thanks. I just happened to use jsch several days ago. Obviously, I have many things to learn. I will read the RFC's. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Before reading the RFCs, try to read the [JSch manual](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Manual) - it is shorter, and more JSch specific. Also, you only need the overview [RFC 5251](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4251), not the technical details of the protocol, I think.

Comment: One cannot 'send' an 'input stream' to 'commands'. You write, "the input stream will be sent to these commands as input". Please consider rephrasing this to make sense.

Comment: @JonathanKomar I think it is quite clear what is meant here – the data which goes through the input stream will be read by the commands. I replaced "sent" with "forwarded", but feel free to propose a better wording here.

Comment: Without back and forth, if it were clear, I wouldn't be commenting on it. I am not knowledgeable enough to write about Jsch. The problem is not in the word choice, I don't think, rather syntax or something. A command is not a consumer. It cannot be the [patient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_(grammar)) in a sentence (or makes no sense as a patient). Not here to point figures at non-native language users. I just want a clear answer. My best guess is that 'to' does not belong in, "the input stream will be forwarded to these commands as input", making "input stream" the patient.

Comment: The "sequence of programs which will be ran by executing the command" is what I shorted to "commands" in this sentence. Those programs can read from their standard input stream, and the SSH protocol (as well as the JSch client library) provides a way of feed data into this stream from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

There is still one more important difference between exec channel and shell channel: The shell channel will establish the shell environment, for example, the environment variables, while the exec channel won't.

Answer (score -1):

Exec channel will only supports Kch commands, for example, `ls -l`. If you will try to run any shell job, it will throw an error such as `ksh: run_pass: not found`