# jsch change directory and get contents

Tags: java, jsch

In jsch if we issue the command `cd ../ && pwd` and if the result is `/home` .Next time if i execute the command `ls` will jsch output me the contents of `/home`.I do expect so ..

```
          Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec"); 
          ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("cd ../ && pwd");

          channel.connect();
          channel.run();

          ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("ls");
```

Answer (score 8):

It [looks like](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Shell,_Exec_or_Subsystem_Channel#Shell_Channel) ChannelExec serves the purpose of executing a single command. But for a complete explanation look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265278/whats-the-exact-differences-between-jsch-channelexec-and-channelshell).

Therefore you could rewrite the code like this:

```
Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec"); 
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("cd ../ && pwd && ls");
channel.connect();
channel.run();
```