# How to cope with interactive Linux commands?

Tags: java, android, bash, ssh, jsch

I have code which allow me to connect through ssh, run a command and get response back. It works fine but only for the non-interactive commands (like: `ls`, `df` which gives the result back immediately after their run). The problem is when I'm trying to run some interactive command like `top` or `passwd` code is waiting forever for the response (and of course getting none).

How to cope with interactive commands? I really don't care about the output, I just wanna to run it.

```java
public String runCommand(String command)  throws Exception {

    // SSH Channel
    ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");      

    // Execute command
    channelssh.setCommand(command);
    channelssh.connect();     

    InputStream inputStream = channelssh.getInputStream(); 
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
        stringBuilder.append('\n');
    }

    channelssh.disconnect();
    return stringBuilder.toString();   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, You can use ChannelShell. Here is an example: [Shell.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html). And this post clarify differences between exec and shell: [what's the exact differences between jsch ChannelExec and ChannelShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265278/whats-the-exact-differences-between-jsch-channelexec-and-channelshell)

2, I tried ChannelExec.setPty(true). And in this way, I could get output. However, it didn't stop.